# selected product price from other sites like flipcart,amazon

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a general question...In php is it possible to get a selected product price from other sites like flipcart,amazon etc.
For example if I search for LCD Tv I want to get its price from different shopping sites like amazon,jabong ...etc to list like this. 
Amazon price--40,000 RS
Flipcart price--40,000 RS

if the product is
 http://www.flipkart.com/hp-15-g009ax-notebook-apu-quad-core-a8-4gb-1tb-free-dos-2gb-graph-g8d85pa/p/itmdwz2gzgkac5fp?pid=COMDWZ2GYN3NKGPH&otracker=ch_vn_laptop_main_Featured%20Laptops_prd_img

how can I get its price...
If possible can you please direct me how it can be done? thanks in advance...

Comment: you can use YQL Web Service to get entire html of that page and fetch price by class or id of that tag which will be common for all the price tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to search about their APIs.

Amazon provide, a rich library set "Amazon Marketplace" to search, and get information about different products.

Likewise you can find for others.

Comment: Can you give exact link where I can get Amazon Marketplace APIs?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that with PHP, my suggestion is cURL ([link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)).

The idea is that you'll request the page information from your URL and then parse the HTML content you get, looking for the price.

On that specific URL, for example, the price is in the following tag:

```
<span class="fk-font-verybig pprice vmiddle fk-bold"> Rs. 29890</span>
```

So when parsing, just loog for that tag and get its content